# diverging implicit expansion for type io.circe.Encoder[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Any]]

Tags: json, scala, circe

I wrote this code

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.parser._, io.circe.syntax._
Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> "a").asJson.toString
```

but I get the following error

```
cmd35.sc:1: diverging implicit expansion for type 
io.circe.Encoder[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Any]]
starting with method encodeMapLike in object Encoder
val res35 = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> "a").asJson.toString
                              ^
```

Comment: And what would you expect instead of error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot serialize `Map[Int, Any]` directly with circe. If `Int` or `String` are only allowed for values then use `Map[Int, Either[Int, String]]` instead with a custom `Encoder` like [here](https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/216).